# dplyr/tidyr: Spread and Get Unique Values of Another Column

Tags: r, tidyr

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- tribble(
  ~cluster, ~sequence, ~proportion,
  1,   'A', 0.10,
  1,  'AB', 0.09,
  1,  'AC', 0.08,
  1, 'ABC', 0.06,

  2,   'D', 0.11,
  2,   'B', 0.11,
  2,  'DB', 0.09,
  2,  'DC', 0.08,
  2,  'AC', 0.07,
  2, 'ADC', 0.06,

  3,   'D', 0.12,
  3,  'BA', 0.10,
  3,  'BB', 0.04,
  3,  'BC', 0.03,
  3,  'BF', 0.03
)
```

How do I transform it to this:

```
y <- tribble(
  ~'cluster1', ~'cluster2', ~'cluster3',
    'A',   'D',  'D',
   'AB',   'B', 'BA',
   'AC',  'DB', 'BB',
  'ABC',  'DC', 'BC',
     '',  'AC', 'BF',
     '', 'ADC',   ''
)
```

That is, I need to spread the unique values of `cluster` across as columns and get the values of `sequence`, (which are already unique) into each of the `clusterX` columns, in descending order of `proportion`.

Note: Each `cluster` will have a different number of unique `sequences`, resulting in the empty values at the bottom of some `clusterX` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a couple `tidyr`/`dplyr` steps. Order the data by proportion. Then within each cluster, add row numbers to preserve this order and satisfy `spread`'s unique identifier requirements. Drop proportion; spread; and drop the row numbers.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>%
  arrange(-proportion) %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  select(-proportion) %>%
  spread(key = cluster, value = sequence, sep = "") %>%
  select(-row)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   cluster1 cluster2 cluster3
#>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 A        D        D       
#> 2 AB       B        BA      
#> 3 AC       DB       BB      
#> 4 ABC      DC       BC      
#> 5 <NA>     AC       BF      
#> 6 <NA>     ADC      <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Check with `ldply` from `plyr`after `split`

```
df=plyr::ldply(split(x$sequence,x$cluster), rbind)
col=df$.id
df$.id=NULL
df=data.frame(t(df))

names(df)=paste('cluster',col)
df
  cluster 1 cluster 2 cluster 3
1         A         D         D
2        AB         B        BA
3        AC        DB        BB
4       ABC        DC        BC
5      <NA>        AC        BF
6      <NA>       ADC      <NA>
```